# Convert sync generator function that takes a sync iterable to async generator function that takes an async iterable

Tags: python, python-asyncio, generator

I have a sync generator function that I can't change (since it's in library) that itself accepts a sync iterable.

But I would like to use it from an async context, passing it an async iterable, and without blocking the event loop during iteration. How can I do this?

For example say we have `my_gen` that takes an iterable of integers that is designed to work in a sync context.

```py
sync_input_iterable = range(0, 10000)
sync_output_iterable = my_gen(input_iterable)
for v in output_iterable:
    print(v)
```

But I would like to use it like this:

```py
async def main():
   # Just for example purposes - there is no "arange" built into Python
   async def arange(start, end):
        for i in range(start, end):
            yield(i)
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

   async_input_iterable = arange(0, 10000)
   async_output_iterable = # Something to to with `my_gen`
   async for v in async_output_iterable:
       print(v)

asyncio.run(main())
```

what could the `# Something...` be to make this work?

Comment: Just leave `my_gen` and write a simple async version of it.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest this is specifically when it’s not that trivial to do so. Say hundreds of lines of code in library that doesn’t have an async interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `` # Something to to with `my_gen` `` could have two components

1. A `to_async_iter` to convert the output of the generator function to an async iterable. This works by iterating over it in a thread using `asyncio.to_thread`, which avoids blocking the event loop.
2. A `to_sync_iter` function to convert the input async iterable to a sync iterable to be passed to the generator function. This works by iterating over it from sync code using `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe`, which makes sense since this is running from a different thread because of `to_async_iter`.

```py
import asyncio

def to_sync_iterable(async_iterable, loop):
    done = object()
    async_it = aiter(async_iterable)
    while (value := asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(anext(async_iterable, done), loop).result()) is not done:
        yield value

async def to_async_iterable(sync_iterable):
    # to_thread errors if StopIteration raised in it. So we use a sentinel to detect the end
    done = object()
    it = iter(sync_iterable)
    while (value := await asyncio.to_thread(next, it, done)) is not done:
        yield value
```

Used for example as follows:

```py
async def main():
    async def arange(start, end):
        for i in range(start, end):
            yield(i)
            await asyncio.sleep(0)

    # For example purposes
    def my_gen(iterable):
        for a in iterable:
            yield a * 2

    async_input_iterable = arange(0, 10000)
    sync_input_iterable = to_sync_iterable(async_input_iterable, asyncio.get_running_loop())
    sync_ouput_iterable = my_gen(sync_input_iterable)
    async_output_iterable = to_async_iterable(sync_ouput_iterable)
    async for v in async_output_iterable:
        print(v)

asyncio.run(main())
```

This is inspired by the code at https://github.com/uktrade/stream-zip/issues/87#issuecomment-1695123135 that does something similar to wrap stream-zip to make it work in an async context.

I can't really speak to its performance.